# Net Send command in Windows 10 Home Edition

Tags: cmd, windows-10

How would I send a message, for example, to all the hosts on my LAN ? In windows XP, one would use net send: `net send * Hello Wold !`

How is that possible in Windows 10 ? I can see that they removed this command, so is there an equivalent ?

Moreover, if I try to use **msg.exe** as an alternative, I get the error-message:

> **`msg`** is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable
>   program or batch file.

Answer (score 7):

This was already removed in Vista, but you can [use msg.exe](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/brad_rutkowski/2007/08/06/net-send-in-windows-vista/) instead:

```
msg.exe /server:brad-dc-01 console "Your machine needs to be rebooted."
```

Comment: @P.Soutzikevich, msg.exe isn't distributed with Windows 10 Home Edition, so you'll have to look for a substitute. You can ask on superuser.com.

Comment: Thanks man! Will do.

Comment: @P.Soutzikevich Although there's no msg.exe in win10 Home, but you can just copy one from win7 or win10 into win10 Home's system32 directory. It works fine.

Comment: Next error: Error 1722 getting session names

Comment: @Yeheshuah, you need write the exact hostname to be reached. I give that error when I write a mispelled hostname.